# VDHL error: converted type of object near text or symbol "UNSIGNED" must match std_logic_vector type of target object

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

I'm getting this error when I try to compile some VHDL code: `Error (10409): VHDL Type Conversion error at <line>: converted type of object near text or symbol "UNSIGNED" must match std_logic_vector type of target object`.

I think I understand that this error is saying `a` is instantiated as `std_logic_vector`, but since I have added `unsigned` when I use `a` in the architecture, they are not the same type anymore so they cannot be properly converted. However, when I try to add `unsigned` in the entity declaration for `SW` or in the signal declaration, I get another error saying "unsigned" is never used. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
library ieee;           
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity E is 
    port( SW:   in   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
          LEDG: out      std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)   
            ); 
end entity E; 

architecture main of E is 
signal a, b, c: std_logic_vector; 

begin 

a <= unsigned(SW(4 downto 0));
b <= unsigned(SW(9 downto 7));
c <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b);
 
// non-relevant code

end architecture main;
```

Comment: The semantic error violated is described in IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.1 Simple signal assignments, para 2 sentence 2: "For a simple waveform assignment, the base type of the value component of each transaction produced by a waveform element on the right-hand side shall be the same as the base type of the signal denoted by the target." Here the expression and target type have different base types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VHDL is very strict about types, it won't convert one type into another one unless you explicitly tell it to.

So to fix your error, you simply have to convert the `unsigned` value back to an `std_logic_vector`, i.e.:

```
a <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(SW(4 downto 0)));
b <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(SW(9 downto 7)));
```

However, there's not really any reason to convert to `unsigned` and then convert back to `std_logic_vector` straight away. So you might as well just do:

```
a <= SW(4 downto 0);
b <= SW(9 downto 7);
```

However, in both cases you'll still get errors, because you didn't define the length of `a`, `b` and `c`. So you should fix those declarations:

```
signal a : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal b : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal c : std_logic_vector(? downto ?); -- Can't infer this from your code.
```

Comment: I have to use unsigned because the "+" operator is not defined otherwise. When I implement std_logic_vector as you have suggested, I get the error "can't determine definition of operator "+""

Comment: @elben Don't assign unsigned expressions to std_logic_vector targets. Try `c <= std_logic_vector ('0' & unsigned(a) + unsigned(b));`. This assignment relies on operator precedence in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.1 "Where the language allows a sequence of operators, operators with the same precedence level are associated with their operands in textual order, from left to right." With a, b, c declaration subtype indications a fix can be shown to compile, simulation or synthesis would demonstrate valid index ranges. Only one operand needs to be the target length. See package body numeric_std "+".

Comment: @elben Then why not simply declare `a`, `b`, and `c` to be `unsigned` types?

Comment: @Darhuuk that's what I ended up doing, and it worked. Thanks!